# How to print text together with variable results

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a calculator and it is ok. It is showing the results but I want to add a text together with the results. For exemple:

You spend "variable result" dollars in the transaction.

The results appear after I click in the calculate button. And I want the same thing for this text. Everything appear together after clicking on the button.

What I'm using to show the results

```
document.querySelector("#example").innerHTML = pri_gra;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to print a variable and text together is like so:

```
 console.log("This is the text", variableName);
```

or

```
var b = 30;
console.log(`This is the text, and ${b} is the variable`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below

```
document.querySelector("#example").innerHTML = "You spend " + pri_gra + " dollars in the transaction.";
```